# how can I add up the value within a period defined by another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, sum

[image: Table example]

how can I add up values in Table2 which is between the date in Table 1? Thanks!

Comment: Please don't add images add only text https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead()` (or `lag()`) to generate intervals from `table1`, then join `table2`, and aggregate by interval:

```
select
    t1.start_date,
    t1.end_date,
    sum(t2.value) add_up_value
from (
    select date start_date, lead(t1.date) over(order by date) end_date
    from table1
) t1
inner join table2 t2
    on t2.date >= t1.start_date and t2.date < t1.end_date
group by t1.start_date, t2.end_date
```

Comment: does lead() function available in MySQL 5.7?

Comment: @sasho: no, it was added in MySQL 8.0. Are you running 5.7?

Answer (score 0):

With a self join and aggregation:

```
select t.startdate, t.enddate,
  sum(value) addupvalue
from (
  select 
    t.date startdate, 
    case 
      when min(tt.date) = max(m.date) then max(m.date)
      else date_sub(min(tt.date), interval 1 day) 
    end enddate
  from table1 t inner join table1 tt
  on tt.date > t.date
  cross join (select max(date) date from table1) m
  group by t.date 
) t 
inner join table2 t2
on t2.date between t.startdate and t.enddate
group by t.startdate, t.enddate
order by t.startdate desc
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oFGyHs7uXrXwmL5po1R4ZH/1).
Results:

```
| startdate  | enddate    | addupvalue |
| ---------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| 2020-04-01 | 2020-04-08 | 37         |
| 2020-03-25 | 2020-03-31 | 29         |
```